# Change From-address using smtp.live.com

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, smtp

Good day!

I'm developing an emailer and I know gmail won't allow this. But can hotmail? Or not?

Reason:

I don't want the recipients to see the "donotreply@hotmail.com" as the sender. I want them to see the email of the user (that is saved in database)

UPDATE:
I want to show the "user_email@hotmail.com" instead of "donotreply@hotmail.com"

See code below

```
     var sender = "user_email@hotmail.com";
     var emailMsg = new MailMessage(sender, "recipient@domain.com", "The Subject", "Email body")
     {
         IsBodyHtml = true,
     };

     var smtp = new SmtpClient()
     {
         EnableSsl = true,
         Timeout = 600000,
         Port = 587,
         Host = "smtp.live.com",
         UseDefaultCredentials = false,
         DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
         Credentials = new NetworkCredential("donotreply@hotmail.com", "thepassword")
     };
     smtp.Send(emailMsg);
     emailMsg.Dispose();
```

The variable "sender" is set as the "From" Property of MailMessage class but it is not showing when I recieved the email. Still the "donotreply@domain.com"... Am I missing something? Or it is not possible like smtp.gmail.com...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: at minimum, you should show your code and where you are having problem, stating what you're trying to accomplish and where you are getting an error. This will show for others that you are trying, not only expecting others to "work for you" :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not having any errors or whatsoever... I'm just asking if my question is possible or not since I haven't seen anything that says "smtp.live.com does not allow this and that" unlike smtp.gmail.com (or Google), that overwrites anything and sets back to the SMTP credentials you specified.

Comment: Asking something without trying to solve the question yourself firstbis not a way to show effort. When you try and test some ideas and fo some research and show some tryingsn(code that didnt work), this is show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ReplyTo value of SMTP object.